# Knockotjs Validation. Passing function gives undefined, because of property order inside VM

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, knockout-validation

validation works fine if validation properties are placed after "HasError" property in VM.
In the case that the property placed before HasError I will get "parameters.hasError" as undefined. I think it's because the property "HasError" is not defined to that time.
Is there any solution without changing the order of the properties inside VM to make it work.

Thanks!

```
self._BusTypeDefault = function(param) {
            var ret = param.BusType;

            if(typeof(ret)==='undefined') {
                ret = '';
            }
            else if(ko.isObservable(ret)) {
                ret = ret.peek();   
            }

            return ret;
        };

         self.BusType = ko.observable(self._BusTypeDefault(init)).extend({maxLength: {message: $Resources.PCIBUSError(), maxFieldLength: 255,hasError: self.HasError }});           

    self._HasErrorDefault = function(param) {
            var ret = param.HasError;

            if(typeof(ret)==='undefined') {
                ret = false;
            }
            else if(ko.isObservable(ret)) {
                ret = ret.peek();   
            }

            return ret;
        };

        self.HasError = ko.observable(self._HasErrorDefault(init)).extend({errorAggregation: {}});  

ko.extenders.maxLength = function (target, parameters) {
  //add some sub-observables to our observable
  target.hasMaxLengthError = ko.observable();
  target.validationMessageMaxError = ko.observable();

  //define a function to do validation
  function validate(newValue) {
    var preValue = target.hasMaxLengthError();

    if (newValue.length >= parameters.maxFieldLength) {
      target.hasMaxLengthError(true);
      target.validationMessageMaxError(parameters.message || "This field is required");
    }
    else {
      target.hasMaxLengthError(false);
      target.validationMessageMaxError("");
    }

    if (parameters.hasError != null && target.hasMaxLengthError() !== preValue && typeof preValue !== 'undefined') {
      parameters.hasError(target.hasMaxLengthError());
    }
  }

  //initial validation
  validate(target());

  //validate whenever the value changes
  target.subscribe(validate);

  //return the original observable
  return target;
};
```

Comment: From looking at your code, I do not see an alternative to changing the order. But on the other hand it is really hard to understand what you are trying to achieve. 
Are you using https://github.com/Knockout-Contrib/Knockout-Validation?
Is maxLength important for that issue?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a function to delay the interpretation of hasError:

```
    this.myObservable = ko.observable(1).extend({ myExtender : { hasError: function () { return self.hasError } } });
```

Then in the extender you'll need to call the function to actually get the observable behind:

```
ko.extenders.myExtender = function (target, params) {
    function validate(newValue) {
        alert("New Value: " + newValue + " ; Has Error: " + params.hasError()());
    }
    target.subscribe(validate);
}
```

See this example: http://jsfiddle.net/7ywLN/